# Finding nearby triangles using the 3D pipeline?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d, mesh, polygons

Say you have a mesh. Consider one of the triangles. Say you want to know **which triangles are neighbours of that triangle**.

In fact:

Does OpenGL (or some other aspect of the 3D pipeline) "know" this information in some way ?

The only way I know to find adjacent triangles, is to simply look through all the vertices of the mesh.

My question:

At the actual 3D pipeline level, **does "the hardware" know which triangles are adjacent**??

Or is there some sort of magic, perhaps Shader-level approach that instantly gives these answers?

Or does, perhaps, the physics-level, in some way, know quickly which tris of a collision mesh are adjacent?

Or perhaps, can you gain this info by writing a custom shader, does the shader level "know" this info?

What's the deal, low-level experts??  Thanks

*PS of course, if this info is NOT available "from the hardware", the best thing is to maintain some sort of spatial database of your mesh. Easy enough, but silly if the info is already available from some aspect of the pipeline/hardware. Thanks!*

---

**LATER NOTE** for future readers, I have now discussed this issue extensively with a coupla folx who work towards the hardware.

Here's the answer:

Indeed, in a word, the 3D pipeline **does NOT know** about neighbouring triangles: it's that simple. A vertex is rendered only with regard to the other two in the **same** triangle, and that's it, just as Anteru explains.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OpenGL doesn't know nor care about what is close. It renders each triangle individually. The only case in which neighbouring triangles are relevant is if you use geometry shaders, but in this case, you must provide the adjacency information.

For rendering, the hardware only cares about which vertices are shared, so it doesn't shade them more often than necessary if possible (i.e., if they fit into the vertex cache.)

Comment: It doesn't keep track which are shared, but it keeps a list of those which are shaded in the cache so if a new vertex is requested via the index buffer, it can check if it's already shaded/cached. See here: http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-3/ for a super-detailed explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of Open GL is it just draws what you tell it.  It doesn't maintain any internal lists or hierarchies.  So no, it would not.

Answer (score 1):

Open GL ES may not know what triangles are "near" each other, but the tile-based deferred renderer in the GPU used by iOS device hardware probably does, at least down to the "same tile" level.  However this information is opaque to the app's code.

Comment: Try googling PowerVR and/or Imagination Technologies.  There appear to be a few white papers on their site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create neighboring data structure. If mesh is stored as:

- list of vertices
- list of triangles where each triangle is triple of vertex indices.

Than it is easy for each vertex to create list of triangle indices where that vertex is used. With that, for checking neighboring triangles it is enough to test only triangles from 3 lists.

Comment: Are meshes so large that you need database? For this approach some identification of vertices and triangles is needed. If there will not be too much delete operations, than lists with object id's same as position in list is good implementation. If you will have lot of delete operations than map (dictionary) is appropriate.